# C# dynamic & COM objects

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, .net-4.0

[from here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/9789/c-40-goes-dynamic-a-step-too-far/)

> A very big advantage of dynamic types comes when you start to think
>   about C#’s relationship with external and non-native objects – COM
>   objects in particular. In this case a dynamic type is resolved using
>   the COM IDispatch interface and this in turn means that you can use
>   COM objects “raw”, i.e. without a Primary Interop Assembly (PIA). As
>   many COM objects make extensive use of the variant type, which can
>   store any of a number of standard data types, being able to use
>   dynamic types in place of variants is a big simplification.

*I already know how dynamic is used in C# , However -  I want to know  how  it is done.(generally with COM)*

looking at *Office COM object model* example :

```
(Excel.Range)excel.Cells[1,1]).Value= "some string"
```

The cast *has to be included* because the `PIA` uses object types to represent variants

Now (2010 ...), with dynamic it can be done with :

```
excel.Cells[1,1].Value= "some string"
```

**But**

An object can provide its binding semantics by implementing `DynamicObject`

such as :

```
public class MyClass: DynamicObject
{
  public override bool TryInvokeMember (  InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

So my question :

Did MS `[changed] or [added code] or [now-inherit-DynamicObject]`  the COM objects in order to allow `excel.Cells[1,1].Value= "some string"` to work ?

Did they re-build this whole mechanism ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the secret sauce is COM here.  This is done with only 2 interfaces and 5 methods.  The first one is IUnknown, an interface implemented by all COM objects.  It has 3 methods:

- AddRef(), increments the reference count on a COM object.  This is a memory management function, as long as the count is non-zero the object stays alive.  Storing a pointer to a COM object requires calling IUnknown.AddRef().
- Release(), decrements the reference count.  The opposite of AddRef and must be called when an interface pointer is no longer used.  The COM object is released when the count reaches zero.  This function is the core reason behind the rather infamous use of Marshal.ReleaseComObject() in .NET code that uses Office.  It normally gets called by the finalizer of a COM wrapper.
- QueryInterface(), asks the COM object to return a pointer to another interface. In the scope of this question, that's how C# gets the IDispatch interface pointer.

The IDispatch interface is the one that implements dynamic binding, the rough equivalent to DynamicObject.  It has 4 methods, 2 of which are important in this context:

- GetIDsOfNames(), converts a name to a number, a *dispid*.  This is how an identifier in a C# program can be matched to a method or property name on the COM object.
- Invoke(), calls the COM method of property getter/setter, using the dispid

That's the big picture, use the MSDN Library if you want to know more about these interfaces.

Comment: There are *some* aspects I miss from the COM days...the all-powerful "QueryInterface" being one of them...

Comment: This is being added back to .NET 5: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/33060

Answer (score 2):

The DLR (which is what the dynamic keyword offers interface to) uses "binders" to interface with the dynamic object proper (there is a C# binder, VB binder, COM binder etc.). The COM binder is a separate component that uses the "traditional" COM interop, which is not replaced and can still be used without dynamic. It was enhanced for .NET 4.0, but not just for dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic` with any type. You need to derive from `DynamicObject` only when you want *your* classes to provide a dynamic interface.

The following line works, without requiring DateTime to inherit from DynamicObject:

```
dynamic myDate=DateTime.Now;
```

**EDIT**

As to how COM+ supports dynamic binding - it always did. In fact, the documentation explains exactly how this is done.

COM always supported its own kind of dynamic binding through the IDispatch interface which works roughly like DynamicObject. IDispatch allows an object to respond to queries for specific interfaces and the methods it supports.

`dynamic` can use the IDispatch interface for raw COM objects, where you don't have a type library or a proxy. In other cases,  `dynamic` will call the proxy methods without going through the IDispatch interface.

Dynamic binding in COM introduces a performance hit, due to the multiple calls needed to extracta a specific interface and invoke its methods. In the VB6 days people tried to minimize or eliminate the use of dynamic binding by using type libraries. This is sound advice for .NET as well.

Comment: and this relates to com in........? (I know that dynamic leaves the execution to runtime)

Comment: I mean (like you said) MS wanted _their_ classes also to provide a dynamic interface. so instead of `(Excel.Range)excel.Cells[1,1]).Value= "some string"` ---->`excel.Cells[1,1].Value= "some string"` my question is did they changed _anything_ in order to allow that

Comment: See the edit. They didn't have to change anything, COM always supported dynamic binding through IDispatch

Comment: So for what this Idispatch was used **before dynamic** ?